# Storing a list of songs linked to event mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a database in MySQL that currently lists approximately 1500 concerts and events. Now, the plan is to add setlists (list of the songs performed at the concerts) for all the concerts in the database. Basically this will mean a lot of repeated values (songs performed at many concerts), and I would really appriciate some input on what the best approach would be.

I initially started out with a database similar to this;

```
| eventID | edate | venue | city | setlist |
```

The field setlist was basically text data, where I could paste the list of songs and parse through it to put each song on a new line with php. This works, and editing the text and running order was like editing a text document. Now, obviously this was pretty simple, but has drawbacks and limitations. Simple things like getting stats on songs performed is probably very difficult, right?

So, what is the best way to store the setlist value?
Create a new table that adds a new row for each song performed, and that has a foreign key linking to eventID? How would I best retain (and edit, if needed) the running order of the songs in that table? Any other suggestions?

Thanks for any input or advice on this, as I would love to get some help before I start adding all the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a table that holds each song performed at a specific event:

```
| songId | eventID | song |
```

Where `eventID` can be duplicated in multiple rows to show each song performed at that event.

This way you can query all the times a specific song was performed, and also get all songs (the setlist) for a specific event by querying on the `eventID`.

Comment: Thanks - sounds like the best way to go, so I will give it a try. How should I store the running order? Users are able to edit this if there are mistakes. Would it be a good idea to use SMALLINT to store the position within the setlist?

Comment: You can add another column `| order |` or something like that to record the running order.  I personally always use INT but I don't work with large databases. I would assume that SMALLINT would be better because you won't have very many songs performed at each performance.

Comment: @joakimvr will you accept my answer if it worked for you?

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much. Will still need to play around with the best way of storing the running order, but I took your advice there as well and it's probably the best way.